# RestException [Error] : Invalid Parameter - Twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp

I am trying to send a WhatsApp message using approved template to my phone using twilio+ nodejs. I am struck with this error from past few days.

My code looks like this.

```
client.messages
.create({ messagingServiceSid: "MG0XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
 contentSid:"HTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
from: "whatsapp:+91999999XXXX", 
contentVariables: { 1: "Name", }, to: "whatsapp:+91789XXXXXXX", })
 .then((message) => { 
console.log(message); 
return success(res, "message sent ", []); }) 
.catch((err) => { 
console.log(err);
 return failure(res, "Some error ocurred", err.message); 
});
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Below is the error message

```
RestException [Error]: Invalid Parameter at success (/home/gt-10/GT-Work/gt-web-services/gt-api/node_modules/twilio/lib/base/Version.js:79:23) at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) 
{ 
status: 400, code: 20422, moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20422', details: undefined
 }
```

Comment: Can you please paste the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

As [error 20422](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/20422) says, you called the API with invalid parameters. I assume it's because you used a messaging service **and** a WhatsApp sender in this call. Try to move the messaging service sid to the `from` param as mentioned [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/send-templates-created-with-the-content-editor):

```js
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages
      .create({
         contentSid: 'HXXXXXXXXX',
         from: 'MGXXXXXXXX',
         contentVariables: JSON.stringify({
           1: 'Name'
         }),
         to: 'whatsapp:+18551234567'
       })
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

Comment: I tried the above one also and still facing the same error. Please help me understand it further.@IObert

Comment: I don't think it's possible that you get the very same error with the code above. Did you check if you are using the most recent version of the twilio package?

Comment: yes   "twilio": "^4.15.0"